# Why am I getting errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure, what did I miss for this to happen? No matter how hard I try to change values around, it always give me the same error. By the way, that database is in mySQL done through Java code. Here it is the first table:

First table (tableName = DoctorsDetails)

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + 
        " (doctor_id INT not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,"+ 
        " first_name VARCHAR(50)," +
        " mid_name VARCHAR(50)," + 
        " last_name VARCHAR(50)," + 
        " tel VARCHAR(32)," + 
        " fax VARCHAR(32)," + 
        " email VARCHAR(40)," +
        " agenda TEXT," +
        " PRIMARY KEY (doctor_id))" + 
        " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

And this is the 2nd table (tableName = Students):

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + 
        " (student_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE," + 
        " first_name VARCHAR(50)," +
        " mid_name VARCHAR(50)," +
        " last_name VARCHAR(50)," +
        " age INT(50)," +
        " class INT(11)," +
        " gender CHAR(1)," +
        " doctor_id INT," +
        " diseases SET('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')," + // TODO: replace the values in set with real
        " more_info TEXT," +
        " height INT(255)," +
        " weight INT(255)," +
        " waist INT(255)," +
        " appointment VARCHAR(50)," + 
        " PRIMARY KEY (student_id)," + 
        " CONSTRAINT FK_StudentDoctor"+
        " FOREIGN KEY(doctor_id) REFERENCES doctors(doctor_id))" +
        " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

Could you guys look through it? I have been looking for it for 2 days, can't figure it out why am I getting this error. Never had this before when I studied MySQL 2 years ago. Did something in MySQL change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first table name is `DoctorsDetails`, so your foreign key clause for your second table should be as follows.

```
FOREIGN KEY(doctor_id) REFERENCES DoctorsDetails(doctor_id)
```

Comment: OMG how did i not spot that .... i feel so dump :/ I've been playing around with this database from yesterday

Answer (score 0):

you have a table called **DoctorsDetails** and another called again **DoctorsDetails**? this is what I see from your code. you declared a variable `tableName` only once with the value of "DoctorsDetails".

**1-** the second table must have another name. 
**2-** the foreign key you're applying to the second table must reference an existing table having the primary key you are referencing to. And also their data types must be the same.

Comment: refresh the page, it's not really the name of the table. I have declared it somewhere else above in my java code and forgot to include it on this. Sorry for that, i have edited my comment.